# the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary

Tags: flutter

Added fonts in woff and woff2 format.  Visual Studio Code writes, "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. Do you want to open it anyway?".  I open the file and there are strange characters[example of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5cGa.jpg)

Comment: Why are you trying to open a font file?

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are binary files that VS Code doesn't know how to open.

If you're trying to preview the font, both Windows and macOS have this built in. Right click on the font in the VS Code explorer and select "Reveal in File Explorer" or "Reveal in Finder", then double click the font file in the Explorer / Finder window that opens. It should open a preview.

If you want to edit the font you'll need an external program like [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/).